# how to include a php page in an asp one?

Tags: php, asp-classic

The asp page like this:

```
<div class="KBox col5">
  <div class="Text">
    <div><img src="images/index_19.gif" /></div>
    <div class="Title">即时新闻</div>
    <div><img src="images/index_20.gif" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="More"></div>
<iframe frameborder=0 width=100% height=100% scr="http://congzhao.sinaapp.com/1.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

The virtual host I used to run the asp page does not support to run a php one.
So I want include the php page into it, but it does not work. Can anyone tells me how to solve this problem?

Comment: well why does  it have to be php? is it a page on your domain?

Comment: @Matthew - I guess I misunderstood the question then?  OP says that the host *doesn't* actually support PHP, which would not be relevant to the iframe loading.  But if you believe that is the real problem, feel free to rollback.

Comment: @a_m0d, visit the URL. It appears to be a valid PHP generated file. So my assumption is that the iframe domain is on a different PHP enabled server, and it is failing only because of the typo that you have fixed with your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `scr="http://congzhao.sinaapp.com/1.php"` to `src="http://congzhao.sinaapp.com/1.php"`

Answer (score 1):

If your host does not support PHP, this will not work.  The PHP interpreter has to be installed on the server, otherwise you will just be serving up the plain-text PHP source code (a big security risk).

Instead, consider moving your site to a host which does support PHP, or re-write the PHP code in ASP.